# Validation image for URL/Domain using Regex? rails 3

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

I want validate a url that is a image e.g.:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/image.jpg
http://www.mydomain.com/image.png
http://www.mydomain.com/image.jpeg
http://www.mydomain.com/image.gif
```

or any url or domain that end with a picture format:

I have this regex:

```
^[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$
```

You can see http://rubular.com/r/qGInC06jcz

**But this regex don't filter extensions .jpg .jpeg .gif .png**

**I want only allow a url or domain that end with a picture.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could just check the ending of the string. You don't even have to use regex here, but here we go.

```
\.(png|jpg|gif)$
```

http://rubular.com/r/5eXJWKi5xT

Comment: Is there any need for using `.*` in this?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Sorry but how it would work for this expression? `^[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$` Thanks